# JavaFX - Listen to Changes in List

Tags: javafx, arraylist, changelistener

Hi I have a probably quite stupid question. I have just started to play around with 
`Properties` and `ChangeListener`s but have hit a speed bump. I have understood that if I make an `ObjectProperty` containing an `ArrayList` any `ChangeListener` will only fire if the `ArrayList` itself changes. However I want all `ChangeListener`s to fire if

1. The `ArrayList` itself changes.
2. The length of the `ArrayList` changes (that is an element is added or removed).
3. An element in the `ArrayList` is changed to a different one.
4. An element in the `ArrayList` changes, that is the content of an element changes (If the element is a custom class `Person` for instance. I want to fire the `ChangeListener` if the person changes her age for instance.).

Is there some functionality in JavaFX for this already or should I implement this manually? What would be the best way to do this?

/Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot add a listener to a regular `ArrayList` as it is not observable. However, the `FXCollections` package does provide an `ObservableArrayList<E>` that allows you to listen for changed.

Here is a demo program:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObservableList<String> strings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        strings.addAll("One", "Two", "Three");

        strings.addListener((ListChangeListener<String>) change -> {
            while (change.next()) {
                if (change.wasAdded()) {
                    System.out.println(change.getAddedSubList().get(0)
                            + " was added to the list!");
                } else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                    System.out.println(change.getRemoved().get(0)
                            + " was removed from the list!");
                }
            }
        });

        strings.add("Dogs");
        strings.remove("Two");
    }
}
```

There are more methods within the `ListChangeListener` that you can use to get more details about what has been changed. Just read up on it!